# Run Polymer Function

Tags: javascript, function, polymer

In my Polymer Element I have this:

```js
Polymer(
        {
            is: "paperspinner-dom",
            behaviors: [Polymer.NeonAnimationRunnerBehavior],
            properties:
            {
                opened:
                {
                    type: Boolean
                },
                animationConfig:
                {
                    value: function()
                    {
                        return {
                            'showSpinner':
                            {
                                name: 'bounce-in-animation',
                                node: this,
                                timing:
                                {
                                    duration: 1000
                                }
                            },
                            'hideSpinner':
                            {
                                name: 'fade-out-animation',
                                node: this
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            runSpinnerAnimation: function(){
               this.playAnimation('showSpinner');
            }
        });
```

And now I want to know how can I run the function runSpinnerAnimation from any other normal JavaScript. Or can I run the playAnimation function from other javascript files ?

Nils

Comment: Did you try *anything* before posting here?

Comment: Yes but nothings works. The idea from Günter is also not working.

Comment: Then please post what you've tried, otherwise it looks as if you have made no effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: As for the answer, it should work. What do you mean by not working? Is there an error in the console or does the animation just not run? Are you including the webcomponents polyfill? The neon animation behavior files? Doesn't work covers a lot of ground.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
document.body.querySelector('paper-spinner-dom').runSpinnerAnimation();
```